# MySQL Syntax change across version

Tags: mysql

Does mysql's sql syntax change between versions in a backwards incompatible way?

I have a long hand-written script which known to work when our mysql was 5.1, but it doesn't work anymore in 5.6.

If yes, what's the common way to update a handwritten script?

I'm not asking about a specific error since when I correct one I just bump into another. Just asking if such breaking changes occur. I'm a foreigner to sql world, for example old Java code generally does not break with version upgrade. And asking if there's a common way to migrate besides correcting everything by hand?

Comment: Check what error mysql gives, and search for that error. You'll find what has been changed between those versions.

Comment: Look at the mysql documentations for changes in mysql api

Comment: No. Yes. Maybe. What's your query that doesn't work any more? What error do you get? This question is way too open ended to answer.

Comment: I'm not asking about a specific error since when I correct one I just bump into another. Just asking if such breaking changes occur. I'm a foreigner to sql world, for example old Java code generally does not break with version upgrade. And asking if there's a common way to migrate besides correcting everything by hand?

Comment: A Google search for `mysql breaking changes`  unveils a couple of resources that seem to confirm that breaking changes indeed occur from time to time. It's very hard to add any specific advice beyond that. I don't know of any migration tools for mySQL

Comment: Java code does break from one version to another, but maybe you never use the features that are affected. MySQL is the same way. They're usually pretty good about preserving compatibility but once in a while the do need to introduce a new feature that breaks with tradition. Read the release notes on 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 5.7. This is why it's usually a bad idea to let things hang out so long. 5.1 was pulled off of life support three years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The most notable change I've suffered myself is `TYPE` removal in the [`CREATE TABLE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> The older TYPE option was synonymous with ENGINE. TYPE was deprecated
>   in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5. When upgrading to MySQL 5.5 or
>   later, you must convert existing applications that rely on TYPE to use
>   ENGINE instead.

Most MySQL clients at the time would use `TYPE` which prevented SQL dumps from being loaded in 5.x servers. So given that there's at least one example I guess we can state that SQL syntax can change between versions in a backwards incompatible way.

As about common way to update a handwritten script, of course that depends entirely of the nature of the change and your data. I normally used a text editor to replace `TYPE` with `ENGINE` since my dumps used to be small.